# Create page as a file in my theme?

Tags: customization, permalinks, pages

Is it possible to create a single page by just adding a php file inside my theme and add header and footer to it? Yes, I know, this page will not be able to administrate through WP Admin.

I have tried out just adding a file and do like I described above. But without success. I guess fixing a permalink is a problem. How do I fix that?

Someone know how to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand your question please give more info details. Perhaps you are talking about adding template in wordpress.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Page
*/

get_header();?>
```

Paste this in your template at the beginning then select this template from pages in dashboard. Hope it will work.

Comment: No, I don't want this to be a "database row"-page. I want the file it self to be the page. So no, it's not a template I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create a single page by just adding a php file inside my theme and add header and footer to it?

Yes, you can.

> I have tried out just adding a file and do like I described above. But without success.

Whether or not a template will be called into a page will be dependant on the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). How you name your template is very very important. You have to stick to a naming convention that fits in with the template hierarchy. Any names used outside that hierarchy will result in your template not loaded.

Also, never mix template names between hierarchies. You cannot name a single template `archive-{$name}.php`, it will never work. If you have a custom post type which matches `$name`, the hierarchy will (*wrongly*) load that template for the custom post type archive page.

If you need any template to be used outside of normal hierarchy, you'll need to use the generic [`template_include`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) filter or the specific [`{$type}_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template/) filter to include that specific template

Comment: Problem is still that I don't wanna need to create a new "Page" from Admin.

Comment: Well, I have explained what you can do. I don't understand what you need then. You are asking for a single page template, create a page called `single-whatever.php` and use the `single_template` filter to include it. None of this requires any work in admin

Comment: Well, I just still didn't quite understand what to do. For example, how do I use single_template in this case? Have tried doing an easy one just using `single_template` to only return` to return what it gets. But placing a die() inside to see if it even is called. I think I need a more detailed explanation how to do this :/